# Clicking table element using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am working with python and selenium to click on the Upload button on a facebook page. The HTML associated with this seems to have a within a table tag. The html is as in the following image. The button circles is the one I am trying to press.

Can anyone please tell me how should I press this button? I am using Python 3.7

[image]

Comment: are you only want to click on upload button

Comment: Yes, only the upload button.

Answer (score 1):

There is a multiple way to click on button you can try any of one

By using Xpath without wait:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('your Xpath').click()
        print('Button clicked ok')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error in clicking BTN : ' + str(e))

By using Xpath with wait:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, 'your Xpath'))).click()
    print('Button clicked ok')
except Exception as e:
    print('Error in clicking BTN : ' + str(e))
```

By using Css selector:

```
try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a._3m1z').click()
        print('Button clicked ok')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error in clicking BTN : ' + str(e))
```

By using css selector with wait:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a._3m1z'))).click()
    print('Button clicked ok')
except Exception as e:
    print('Error in clicking BTN : ' + str(e))
```

you can copy xpath by right click on element >>copy>>xpath

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I'm using the third option, but that opens a win32 browse file. I am unable to use send_keys functions. Please see the question at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558106/python-selenium-upload-a-file-using-windows-browser

Comment: you welcome if this help you accept my answer that will helps other..