# Interacting with Chrome open file dialog with Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

So I've been struggling with this all day.

The page has a 'Select File' button, plus a 'Save' button, which by default is hidden. When the user clicks 'Select File' Chrome file open dialog displays. After the user picks (types in the name of) a file clicks 'Open' the dialog closes, some validation is done, and if all is well the path of the selected file is displayed on the page, and the 'Save' button is displayed/enabled so the user can click it actually upload the file.

Reading various past threads, I have come to understand that the file open dialog is an HTML INPUT element and has a sendkeys method, just like a text field, so I can interact with it directly.

Consensus from these older threads was that the following should work:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@type, 'file')]")).Clear();
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@type, 'file')]")).SendKeys("SomeFileName.txt");
```

However, when I do this I get an 'element not found' error. I find I need to actually have the dialog displaying. So, I find I first need to click the button that triggers the dialog, and *then* I can address it:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("UploadFileBtnId")).Click()
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@type, 'file')]")).Clear();
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@type, 'file')]")).SendKeys("SomeFileName.txt");
```

Problem is that now the dialog is displayed, continues to display, and there doesn't seem to be any mechanism to close it. It stays up even after the test run itself finishes.

I have also seen it suggested that I can SendKeys to the *button* element that triggers the dialog. To wit:

```
    Driver.FindElement(By.Id("UploadFileBtnId")).SendKeys("SomeFileName.txt");
```

This does not cause an error, and does not trigger the dialog, but neither does it trigger any validation of the input and the save button is never enabled and the test is blocked.

Hoping someone might have a suggestion or two on how to cope with this zombie dialog.

rabbit

Comment: Can you provide more details on the file dialog? Is this the file explorer that is associated with your operating system, or is it an HTML element rendering on the page? Also, including your HTML for the file upload would be helpful -- there may need to be a different selector for your file upload. I always have used the `SendKeys()` method in the past (with a little tweaking) with success.

Comment: Here's a js way to [upload without opening the dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558106/python-selenium-upload-a-file-using-windows-browser)

Answer (score 3):

when the dialog opens, you need to take control from browser controls and shift it to windows dialog box. I am guessing this shifting part is your problem?try this if this is so.After opening dialog, it will pick the file specified,and press enter, dialog box will close, file will be seen uploaded. Works for me, try it!

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(@"C:\File.doc");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
```

Comment: I'm not following how this could possibly work. I assume your Forms.SendKeys() call would send keys to the *test program's* window (if it even has one), but the OP needs to send keys to the *browser* window, which is a completely different Windows process.